# Edit task whoId in Vf page

Tags: visualforce, tasks, multi-select, taskrelation

We have a requirement of editing a task whoid from VF page multi- select list(contacts).The page opens from task custom button.

VF page code block:

```
<apex:page standardController="Task" extensions="controllerclass" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form id="frm">
        <apex:pageblock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:panelGrid style="width:100px;" id="pg">    
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" id="pbs1">
                conatct list to be added as task relation<div style="color:red;font-size:20px;" > * </div>                    
                <apex:actionRegion id="ar">
                    <apex:panelGrid columns="4" id="grid1" >
                        <apex:selectList id="sel1" value="{!leftselected}" multiselect="true" style="width:150px;height:100px;" size="5" >
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!unselectedvalues}" />
                        </apex:selectList>
                        <apex:panelGroup >
                            <br/>                                    
                            <apex:commandButton value=">>" action="{!selectclick}" reRender="grid1"/> <br/><br/>
                            <apex:commandButton value="<<" action="{!unselectclick}" reRender="grid1"/>
                        </apex:panelGroup>
                        <apex:selectList id="sel2" value="{!rightselected}" multiselect="true" style="width:150px;height:100px;" size="5">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!SelectedValues}" />
                        </apex:selectList>

                        <apex:panelGroup id="pg1">                                    
                            <apex:commandButton value="Set Task WhoId" reRender="grid1" action="{!selectPrimaryContact}"/>
                            <br/><br/>
                            <apex:outputText style="font-weight:bold;" value="{!primaryContactName}"></apex:outputText>
                        </apex:panelGroup>
                    </apex:panelGrid>                   
                </apex:actionRegion> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>            
            </apex:panelGrid> 
        </apex:pageblock>       
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex code method:
  //Task tsk id fetching task id via getparameters (click from custom button url)

```
//to select & add multiple contacts from LHS to RHS in multipicklist
public PageReference selectclick(){
        List<SelectOption>  templeft = new List<SelectOption>();
        system.debug('selectedvalues--');
        for(Selectoption s : unselectedvalues)
        {            
            if(leftselected.contains(s.getvalue()))
            {
                SelectedValues.add (new SelectOption(s.getvalue(),s.getlabel()));                
            }
            else
            {
                templeft.add (new SelectOption(s.getvalue(),s.getlabel()));
            }            
        }
        unselectedvalues = templeft;        
        return null;        
    }

    //to select & add multiple contacts from RHS to LHS in multipicklist
    public PageReference unselectclick(){        
        List<SelectOption>  tempRight = new List<SelectOption>();
        system.debug('selectedvalues--');
        for(Selectoption s : selectedvalues)
        {            
            if(rightselected.contains(s.getvalue()))
            {
                unSelectedValues.add (new SelectOption(s.getvalue(),s.getlabel()));                
            }
            else
            {
                tempRight.add (new SelectOption(s.getvalue(),s.getlabel()));
            }            
        }
        selectedvalues = tempRight;        
        return null;
    }

//To select a contact to make it task whoid on form save
    public PageReference selectPrimaryContact(){        
        system.debug('selectedup--');        
        System.debug(rightselected);
        Contact con = new Contact();
        if(rightselected.size()>0){
            con =[Select id,name from Contact where id = :rightselected[0]];
        }
        primaryContactName = con.Name;  
        System.debug(con.Id);
        primaryContactId = con.Id;
        System.debug(primaryContactName+' '+primaryContactId);
        return null;
    }

public void save(){
 //this method updates task with all taskRelations(contacts selected via multi-selectlist)
 if(primaryContactId != '')
        tsk.WhoId= primaryContactId;
     update Tsk;

//post this inserting other taskrelation except whatid & whoid
}
```

On clicking save button , it updates the task with all taskRelations(conatcts selected via multi-selectlist) .It is working fine till there.

But when i am trying to change the task whoid by clicking 'Set Primary Contact' & saving the form ,  I am getting 'Updating the whoId fields for shared activities is not allowed' error on update dml(task update).

Is there any other workaround on this?This is somewhat urgent.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance !

Comment: You seem to have omitted the code that actually sets `WhoId`. Could you make an [edit] to include this?

Comment: Now added in code